# Webservice: html as an animated tree?

Tags: html, web-services, animation, web

I am looking for a web service that displays the html structure of a webpage like a graph.

I have seen an app years ago that looked beautiful. The input was a URL and the output was a flash tree with branches acting like springs and nodes had different colors for different tagnames.

I am not sure if this is an SO question. If not, can you please point me to the right stackexchange page?

Thanks!

Comment: Dear fellow SO-er, if you vote to close it, can you please help me where I could turn with my problem? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if I understood correctly, but here is what I [found](http://www.aharef.info/static/htmlgraph/)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you ment with "graph", 
but as I'm tring to lern to DOMNodes,
I started playing around with a foldable presentation of html.

this is what i got so far:

- source: http://htmlviewer.puggan.se/htmlviewer/htmlviewer.201308131630.phps
- live: http://htmlviewer.puggan.se/htmlviewer/htmlviewer.201308131630.php

```
<?php

    require_once('/mnt/data/www/libs/remote.php');

    if(isset($_GET['debug']))
    {
        $debug_page = file_get_contents("exemple.html");
    }

    $form_page = <<<HTML_BLOCK
<html>
    <head>
        <title>HTML Viewer</title>
        <style>
            #url_input
            {
                width: 800px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- placeholder error -->
        <form action='?' method='post'>
            <label>
                <span>Enter a URL</span>
                <input type='text' name='url' id='url_input' />
            </label>
            <br />
            <input type='submit' value='view HTML' />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
HTML_BLOCK;

    if(isset($_REQUEST['url']) AND $_REQUEST['url'] OR isset($debug_page) AND $debug_page)
    {
        if(isset($debug_page) AND $debug_page)
        {
            $url = 'file:///debugpage.html';
            $page = &$debug_page;
        }
        else
        {
            $url = $_REQUEST['url'];
            $url_parts = parse_url($url);

            if($url_parts['scheme'] != 'http' AND $url_parts['scheme'] != 'https')
            {
                echo str_replace("<!-- placeholder error -->", "<p class='warning'>Bad url-scheme</p>");
                die();
            }

            $hash = isset($url_parts['fragment']) ? $url_parts['fragment'] : FALSE;

            $page = $remote_site->get_page($url);
        }

        if(!$page)
        {
            echo str_replace("<!-- placeholder error -->", "<p class='warning'>Page Empty</p>");
            die();
        }

        $doc = new DOMDocument();
        @$doc->loadHTML($page);

        if(!$doc)
        {
            echo str_replace("<!-- placeholder error -->", "<p class='warning'>Failed to read html</p>");
            die();
        }

        echo <<<HTML_BLOCK
<html>
    <head>
        <title>HTML Viewer</title>
        <style>
            .node
            {
                background-color: rgba(255, 255, 0, 0.01);
                padding-left: 15px;
                border: solid rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.2) 1px;
            }

            .text_node
            {
                max-height: 100px;
                overflow: auto;
            }

            .close DIV.long, .close SPAN.long, .close IMG.long, DIV.short, SPAN.short, IMG.short
            {
                display: none;
            }

            .close SPAN.short, SPAN.long
            {
                display: inline;
            }

            .close DIV.short, .close IMG.short, DIV.long, IMG.long
            {
                display: block;
            }

            .expander
            {
                float: left;
            }
        </style>
        <script>
            DOMTokenList.prototype.replace = function replace(from, to)
            {
                this.remove(from);
                this.add(to);
            };

            DOMTokenList.prototype.togglePair = function togglePair(from, to)
            {
                if(this.contains(from))
                {
                    this.replace(from, to);
                }
                else
                {
                    this.replace(to, from);
                }
            };

        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>{$url}</h1>
        <div id='root_node'>

HTML_BLOCK;
        if($hash)
        {
            $node = $doc->getElementById($hash);
            if($node)
            {
                print_node($node);
            }
            else
            {
                print_node($doc);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            print_node($doc);
        }
        echo <<<HTML_BLOCK

        </div>
    </body>
</html>

HTML_BLOCK;
    }
    else
    {
        echo $form_page;
    }

    function print_node($node)
    {
        if(!$node instanceof DOMNode)
        {
            trigger_error("Bad node: " . (get_class($node) ?: gettype($node)));
            return FALSE;
        }

        $classes = array('node');

        if($node instanceof DOMDocument)
        {
            echo "<div class='node root_node'>";
            if($node->hasChildNodes())
            {
                echo "<!-- child nodes: " . $node->childNodes->length . " -->\n";
                foreach($node->childNodes as $child_node)
                {
                    print_node($child_node);
                }
            }
        }
        else if($node instanceof DOMComment)
        {
            return FALSE;
        }
        else if($node instanceof DOMDocumentType)
        {
            echo "<div class='node dockument_type_node'>";
            echo htmlentities($node->internalSubset);
        }
        else if($node instanceof DOMText)
        {
            if(trim($node->wholeText))
            {
                echo "<span class='short'>...</span>";
                echo "<div class='node text_node data_node long'>";
                //echo nl2br(htmlentities(trim($node->wholeText)));
                echo "<pre>";
                echo htmlentities($node->wholeText);
                //echo get_class($node);
                //var_dump($node);
                echo "</pre>";
                echo "</div>\n";
            }
            else
            {
                return FALSE;
            }
        }
        else if($node instanceof DOMCharacterData)
        {
            echo "<div class='node'>";
            echo "<pre>";
            echo get_class($node);
            //var_dump($node);
            echo "</pre>";
            echo "</div>\n";
        }
        else if($node instanceof DOMElement)
        {
            //content
            if($node->hasChildNodes())
            {
                echo "<div class='node element_node element_node_normal node_element_{$node->tagName} close'>";

                echo "<span class='expander' onclick=\"this.parentNode.classList.togglePair('close', 'open'); \">";
                echo "<img class='short' src='https://www.interfaceways.se/img/icons/bullet_add.png' />";
                echo "<img class='long' src='https://www.interfaceways.se/img/icons/bullet_delete.png' />";
                echo "</span>";

                echo "<span class='tag_open'>";
                echo "<span>&lt;</span>";
                echo "<span class='tag_name'>" . $node->tagName . "</span>";
                print_attributes($node);
                echo "<span>&gt;</span>";
                echo "</span>\n";

                echo "<!-- child nodes: " . $node->childNodes->length . " -->\n";

                echo "<span class='short'>...</span>";
                echo "<div class='long'>";
                foreach($node->childNodes as $child_node)
                {
                    print_node($child_node);
                }
                echo "</div>\n";

                echo "<span class='tag_close'>";
                echo "<span>&lt;/</span>";
                echo "<span class='tag_name'>" . $node->tagName . "</span>";
                echo "<span>&gt;</span>";
                echo "</span>\n";
                echo "</div>\n";
            }
            else
            {
                echo "<div class='node element_node element_node_solo'>";
                echo "<span class='solo_close'>";
                echo "<span>&lt;</span>";
                echo "<span class='tag_name'>" . $node->tagName . "</span>";
                print_attributes($node);
                echo "<span>/&gt;</span>";
                echo "</span>\n";
                echo "</div>\n";
            }
        }
        else
        {
            echo "<div class='node'>";

            echo "<pre>";
            echo get_class($node);
            //var_dump($node);
            echo "</pre>";
            echo "</div>\n";
        }
    }

    function print_attributes($node)
    {
        if(!$node instanceof DOMElement)
        {
            return FALSE;
        }

        if($node->hasAttributes())
        {
            echo " <span class='attributes'>";
            foreach($node->attributes as $node_attribute)
            {
                echo "<span class='attributes'>";
                echo "<span class='attribute_name'>";
                echo htmlentities($node_attribute->name);
                echo "</span>";
                echo "<span>=\"</span>";
                echo "<span class='attribute_value'>";
                echo htmlentities($node_attribute->value);
                echo "</span>";
                echo "<span>\"</span>";
                echo "</span> ";
            }
            echo "</span>";
        }
        else
        {
            echo ' ';
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for your input, sorry for not being more precise. I meant to find exactly the app Felipe Marcos managed to find. (Check it out, it really looks fun!)

Comment: It's require Java, so can't see it from this computer.